# Remove special characters from phone number from xml

Tags: php, xml

I need to remove special characters from phone number before inserting,
for example +91 should be removed. I have tried with preg replace don't know if its correct.

```
//Insert to zoho
    $zoho_api =" ";
    $xml='
    <Leads>
    <row no="1">
    <FL val="Lead Owner">'.GLOBAL_SUPPORT_EMAIL.'</FL>
    <FL val="First Name"></FL>
    <FL val="Last Name">'.$leadArray['full_name'].'</FL>
    <FL val="Email">'.$leadArray['email'].'</FL>
    <FL val="Phone">'.$leadArray['phone_number'].'</FL>
    <FL val="Mobile">'.$leadArray['phone_number'].'</FL>
    <FL val="City Name">'.ucwords($leadArray['city']).'</FL>
    <FL val="Project">'.$leadArray['project_/_villa_/_apartment_name'].'</FL>
    <FL val="Description">'.$time_to_purchase.".".$what_are_u_looking.'</FL>
    <FL val="Lead Status">Created</FL>
    <FL val="Date of Inquiry">'.date('m/d/Y').'</FL>
    <FL val="V21 Customer">TRUE</FL>
    </row>
    </Leads>
    ';

    $query="authtoken=".ZOHO_AUTH_TOCKEN." ".$xml;
```

Comment: show the `$leadArray['phone_number']` value

Comment: Don't remove them, encode them. Even better use an XML API like DOM or XMLWriter that will encode special characters for you. Additionally "+91" is the country code for India, not a special character. Just removing it means that the phone number is no longer valid.